How can I define a CosmosDB composite index to optimise GROUP BY clause, aggregate system functions (MIN,MAX) and filter predicates?
I have a collection with a document schema along the following lines
{
    "CategoryParentId": "{guid}",
    "CategoryId": "{guid}",
    "ProductType": "{string}",
    "Size": {int},
    "Price": {decimal},
    "Discount": {decimal}
}


I execute a query to retrieve the min price and max discount for each category for a given product type and size:
SELECT p.CategoryParentId, p.CategoryId, MIN(p.Price) minPrice, MAX(p.Discount)
FROM p
WHERE p.ProductType = 'Foo' AND p.Size = 5
GROUP BY p.CategoryParentId, p.CategoryId 

With the aid of the following composite index this query is costing around 500 RU:
        [
            {
                "path": "/CategoryParentId",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/CategoryId",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/Price",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/Discount",
                "order": "descending"
            }
        ]

I would like to add a more specific composite index that includes the ProductType and Size properties that will yield less RU cost for my query when included as filter predicates.
I tried adding the following additional composite index, which is a variation of the original that also includes ProductType and Size:
        [
            {
                "path": "/ProductType",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/Size",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/CategoryParentId",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/CategoryId",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/Price",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/Discount",
                "order": "descending"
            }
        ]

After creating the index the cost of the query is still unchanged at around 500 RU.
However, if I amend my query to also group by ProductType and Size, e,g:
SELECT p.ProductType, p.Size, p.CategoryParentId, p.CategoryId, MIN(p.Price) minPrice, MAX(p.Discount)
FROM p
WHERE p.ProductType = 'Foo' AND p.Size = 5
GROUP BY p.ProductType, p.Size, p.CategoryParentId, p.CategoryId

The cost is reduced to only 70 RU, which is significantly better.
However, the additional fields grouped by means the query returns more records than I need, and I have to reduce the result set client side to find the actual best price and max discount per category. This is not ideal, but it demonstrates that the new index can be utilised to improve performance IF I include the two fields in the group by, however including them only in the predicate as in the original query doesn't utilise the index.
Is there a way I can express the composite index to achieve the 70 RU performance with the original query and filter predicate in order to avoid the redundant group by fields?

Let's try to address this in steps.
Step 1:Normal indexes to exclude all properties and include only ProductType and Size since those are the properties you are filtering on.
Step 2: Composite indexes can also be used if you have filters against 2 or more properties. So try making the following composite index.
[
    {
        "path": "/CategoryParentId",
        "order": "ascending"
    },
    {
        "path": "/CategoryId",
        "order": "ascending"
    }
]

Step 3: If you look at the [documentation][1] , it states :

If a query filters on one or more properties and has different
properties in the ORDER BY clause, it may be helpful to add the
properties in the filter to the ORDER BY clause.

So, if you use the composite index which I have suggested, you will need to modify your query with an order by clause, something like below.
SELECT p.CategoryParentId, p.CategoryId, MIN(p.Price) minPrice, MAX(p.Discount)
FROM p
WHERE p.ProductType = 'Foo' AND p.Size = 5
ORDER BY p.ProductType ASC,  p.Size ASC
GROUP BY p.CategoryParentId, p.CategoryId 

Currently there are no indexes to help with MIN and MAX aggregations. So, remove price and Discount from your composite index.
Step 4: You can try adding normal indexes to include for CategoryParentId and CategoryId to see if that improves the performance.
Something else which may help the performance is the partitioning. For example if your DB was partitioned on ProductType, it may help the performance as well.
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#queries-with-a-filter-and-order-by
